# What's the correct sql command to find exact matches?

Tags: php, sql, exact-match

The below code will obviously search for similar results as the query variable but what is the SQL command to search for exact results and not "like"?

```
$query = "SELECT languages.language FROM languages WHERE language LIKE '%".$name."%'";
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Radu: How *do* I assign a value to a variable in PHP?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - a better question is how do i *declare* a variable in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried the `=` operator and removing the `%` wild cards?

Comment: +1: What!? How on earth did you figure that one out!? You're a superstar ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Although I answered what you asked, it is worth pointing out, as others have said, that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks :)

For exact matches:

```
$query = "SELECT languages.language FROM languages WHERE language ='".$name."'";
```

For non matches:

```
$query = "SELECT languages.language FROM languages WHERE language <> '".$name."'";
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: I know, but I just did what he asked, I've put a disclaimer on :)