# How do I use the LIKE function in SQL but for an exact word?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am new to SQL and having and issue.  I want to delete from my database wherever somebody in the description column has the hashtag "#whatever".  I was able to write the following query:

```
select id from table where description_field LIKE "%#whatever%" and user_id=333
```

But if i use the LIKE function here it will delete wherever it matches #whatever but I fear that it might delete something where it has #whateverANDthis.

How can I write a query that deletes a row wherever it ONLY contains "#whatever" in the description and not other variations like "#whateverANDthis" or "#whateverORthis".

I want to delete where it says:

"I had so much fun #whatever"

but not:

"I had so much fun #whateverAndWhatever"

Comment: Do you store multiple tags in `description_field`?

Comment: @juergend yes so a person can have multiple tags in their description.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for "whole word match" in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql)

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in one column! Normalize your data.

Comment: [Duplicate of this problem solved long ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252513/whats-the-correct-sql-command-to-find-exact-matches)

Comment: @juergend I don't think he's storing the hash-tags as tags, just as part of the description - i.e. the user has typed "I had so much fun #whatever"

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes that's right.

Comment: I agree with @juergend, this is not a workable design the way you want to query it. Even if you get the query to work correctly it will be much less efficient than a query on correctly normalized and indexed table.

Comment: This question might get closed as being a duplicate, but even though the other question answers your specific question, I agree with the other comments here that this is not how you should be doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), the regex version of LIKE:

```
WHERE description_field RLIKE '[[:<:]]#whatever[[:>:]]'
```

The expressions `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are leading and trailing "word boundaries".

Comment: thanks i tried using it but i got no returned rows.  I know for sure I have at least 20,000 rows that have that hashtag.

Comment: This should work, so without seeing sample data I can't help. Please create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data and post the link into the question, let me know you've done it and I'll get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to save them in multiple columns but

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE decription_field REGEXP '[[:<:]]#whatever[[:>:]]' and user_id=333
```

could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
select id from table 
where (' ' + description_field + ' ') LIKE "% #whatever %" and user_id=333
```

Comment: It won't find `"#whatever."`, though.

Comment: . . Yes it will.  That's why you added spaces to both sides.  The major issue is that this is SQL Server syntax on a MySQL tagged question.

Answer (score 0):

For your current situation, your query has to cover three scenarios, first word, middle word, and last word.  So your query might resemble this:

```
where user_id = 33
and
(
description_field like '%#whatever %' -- first word
or description_field like '% #whatever %'  -- middle word
or description_field like '% #whatever'  -- last word
)
```

Or, you could work on those regex proposals.  They might be better.